# Is it appropriate to use Sobel operators to find the derivatives of an image?

Tags: image-processing, filters, edge-detection, gradient

Strictly speaking, the $x$ direction derivative should be the difference between the left and right pixel of each pixel. So, then I should be using a $1\times 3$ filter:

\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}

If that is so, why is the Sobel operator a $3\times 3$?
\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&1\\-2&0&2\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}

Is it so that the approximation of the derivative is less susceptible to noise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it adds smoothing in the $y$ direction. The Sobel filter is the [separable combination](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/) of the centered derivative $[−1,\;0,\;1]$ along $x$, and the $3$-point binomial smoother $[1,\;2,\;1]$ along $y$.